# Batch size does not work when using parent/child contexts

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I've been able to confirm this on my application, and a quick sample application I created to confirm this. Here's the setup:

You have two managed object contexts:

```
masterMOC: NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType, tied to persistent store coordinator
mainMOC: NSMainQueueConcurrencyType, child of masterMOC, NOT tied to any store coordinator
```

This setup was inspired from the WWDC video, which suggests we can save on a background thread by setting the `masterMOC` to a private queue and tie it to the persistent store. If you set up an `NSFetchedResultsController` using the `mainMOC` (and it must be the `mainMOC` since that's the one tied to the UI), and set a `fetchBatchSize`, the batch size is disregarded and all entities are faulted in at once. I enabled the SQLite debug annotations, and when scrolling through thousands of rows (with a batch size of 20), no faults are fired what so ever.

If I make one simple adjustment, namely tie the persistent store coordinator to the `mainMOC` and make it a root context (that is, it is no longer a child of master), then the batch size works perfectly, and as I scroll through thousands of rows, several faults are fired.

Is this expected behavior? Am I missing something?

You can download the sample project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tiqzb3msw4w471c/Core%20Data%20master:main.zip)

Comment: I have experienced the same issue in UIManagedDocument which also uses nested contexts: [NSFetchRequest fetchBatchSize does not work with UIManagedDocument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274412/nsfetchrequest-fetchbatchsize-does-not-work-with-uimanageddocument). I have also asked on the Apple dev forums but have not had any response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is limited discussion of nested contexts in the documentation, it only appears in "Core Data Release Notes for iOS v5.0", and in `UIManagedDocument`. The only comment on fetching and nested contexts is:

> fetch and save operations are mediated by the parent context instead of a coordinator.

Given the lack of any disclaimers relating to the functionality of batch fetching with nested contexts, I would suggest it is not expected that batch fetching and nested contexts are incompatible.  However this seems to be the case as the most basic example does not function. *(See test code below)*.

There is also an open radar submission describing the same problem here: http://openradar.appspot.com/11235622, and other problems noted with FetchedResultsControllers and nested contexts: [Duplication of entity when change made by a child ManagedObjectContext is pushed (saved) to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641748/duplication-of-entity-when-change-made-by-a-child-managedobjectcontext-is-pushed).

A possible partial solution could be to add an additional `NSManagedObjectContext` of `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` directly to the same `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` for the sole purpose of serving the `NSFetchedResultsController`. ObjectIDs could then be handed back to the nested child context when the user selects items, and any subsequent editing can then be performed in the nested contexts.

This obviously reduces the benefit of using nested contexts and would require more frequent saving to synchronise between the nested contexts and the `NSFetchedResultsControllers` context.  However depending on the design of the application and the relative benefits of nested contexts vs batch loading this may be useful. *(See example code below)*

**Test code showing failure of simplest case batch fetching in nested contexts:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// Xcode 4.3.3:
// Create a new iOS Master-Detail project called "BatchTest" tick the "Use Core Data" check box.
// Delete all files except the AppDelegate and the BatchTest data model (leave supporting files).
// Delete all properties and methods from AppDelegate.h
// Paste this code into AppDelegate.m
// Switch on core data debugging by editing the "BatchTest" scheme and adding 
//   -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
// To the "arguments passed on launch" list in the "Run" step
// Run.

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Setup the core data stack.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BatchTest" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSURL *appDocsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *storeURL = [appDocsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BatchTest.sqlite"];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:nil];

    NSManagedObjectContext *parentContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    parentContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    NSManagedObjectContext *childContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    childContext.parentContext = parentContext;


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Load some test data and reset the context.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:parentContext];
        }
        [parentContext save:nil];
        [parentContext reset];
    }];


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Test Batched Fetching
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    request.fetchBatchSize = 10;

    // Fetch from the child.
    NSArray *results = [childContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Object 500: %@", [results objectAtIndex:500]);
    // Result is all 1000 rows fetched in full, no subsequent batch fetching for event 500.

    [childContext reset];    
    [parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [parentContext reset];

        // Fetch from the parent.
        NSArray *results = [parentContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Object 500: %@", [results objectAtIndex:500]);
        // Result is 1000 primary keys fetched, followed by a batch of 10 rows to find event 500.

    }];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

**Example code showing use of an additional context to serve an `NSFetchedResultsController` with batching working:**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

// Xcode 4.3.3:
// Create a new iOS Master-Detail project called "BatchTest" tick the "Use Core Data" check box.
// Delete all files except the AppDelegate and the BatchTest data model (leave supporting files).
// Delete all properties and methods from AppDelegate.h
// Paste this code into AppDelegate.m
// Switch on core data debugging by editing the "BatchTest" scheme and adding 
//   -com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
// To the "arguments passed on launch" list in the "Run" step
// Run.

@interface AppDelegate () {
    NSManagedObjectContext *backgroundContext;
    NSManagedObjectContext *editingContext;
    NSManagedObjectContext *fetchedResultsControllerContext;
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject;
}

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Setup the core data stack.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"BatchTest" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

    NSURL *appDocsDirectory = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    NSURL *storeURL = [appDocsDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"BatchTest.sqlite"];

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
    [coordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:nil];

    backgroundContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    backgroundContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    editingContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    editingContext.parentContext = backgroundContext;

    fetchedResultsControllerContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    fetchedResultsControllerContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator;

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Load some test data and reset the context.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [backgroundContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        for (int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
            [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" inManagedObjectContext:backgroundContext];
        }
        [backgroundContext save:nil];
        [backgroundContext reset];
    }];

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Example of three contexts performing different roles.
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // The fetchedResultsControllerContext will batch correctly as it is tied directly 
    // to the persistent store.  It can be used to drive the UI as it is a Main Queue context. 
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
    request.fetchBatchSize = 10;
    NSArray *fetchResults = [fetchedResultsControllerContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];

    // User selects an object in the fetchedResultsControllerContext (i.e. in a UITableView).
    selectedObject = [fetchResults lastObject];
    NSLog(@"**** selectedObject.timeStamp before editing:%@", [selectedObject valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]);

    // Pass the object to the editing context for editing using its objectID.
    NSManagedObjectID *selectedObjectID = selectedObject.objectID;
    NSManagedObject *objectForEditing = [editingContext objectWithID:selectedObjectID];

    // Edit the object
    [objectForEditing setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];

    // Subscribe to save notifications of the background context so the 
    // fetchedResultsControllerContext will be updated after the background save occurs.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(backgroundContextDidSave:) 
                                                 name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
                                               object:backgroundContext];

    // Save the editing context to push changes up to the parent, then background save.
    [editingContext save:nil];
    [backgroundContext performBlock:^{
        [backgroundContext save:nil];
    }];

    return YES;
}

- (void)backgroundContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {

    [fetchedResultsControllerContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    NSLog(@"**** selectedObject.timeStamp after editing:%@", [selectedObject valueForKey:@"timeStamp"]);
    // Merging changes into the fetchedResultsControllerContext would trigger updates
    // to an NSFetchedResultsController and it's UITableView where these set up.

}

@end
```

Comment: Ya but what I liked about having the persistent store being attached to a private queue context was the ability to save in the background, which sounded awesome. Any ideas on how to get that functionality back?

Comment: So the suggestion is to keep the existing setup for most things but just use an additional context to serve only the `NSFetchedResultsController`, i.e. readonly.  You would still edit objects in the nested context and save them in the background.  I assume as `NSFetchedResultsControllers` are mainly used to populate `UITableViews` that you aren't editing whilst the table view is visible and therefore can pass the object selected back to the nested contexts (using it's `objectID`) for editing and then notify the fetched result controllers context on save (in the background).

Comment: You might at worst see a delay before any changes appear in the table view whilst the save is running. But perhaps you can manage any long running saves to a different point if that's an issue.  It's more compacted, but batching is broken so I don't see any other choice except to wait for a fix from Apple.

Comment: Wait, you're allowed to set the same persistent store coordinator to more than one context?

Comment: Yep. The code above should be very easy to get running if you want to experiment.

Comment: Did the solution described above help?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't gotten around to trying it out yet. I don't see why it wouldn't work, but I'm still not sure if a we're allowed to share the same persistent store coordinator between contexts. That sounds like a shady operation. Any documentation excerpts that state this is ok?

Comment: No documentation excepts to hand, however explicitly stated as beneficial setup in WWDC 2010 Session "Session 137 - Optimizing Core Data Performance on iPhone OS" (19:20).  Where is discusses the benefits of contexts sharing a persistent store coordinator and thus sharing a common row cache and saving trips to the database.

Comment: Also, if you've found the answer useful, please consider assigning your bounty as you lose the bounty whether you assign it or not.

Comment: Just noticed from the docs for: `setPersistentStoreCoordinator:` "Note that multiple contexts can share a coordinator"

Answer (score 0):

From [NSFetchRequest Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html):

> When the fetch is executed, the entire request is evaluated and the identities of all matching objects recorded, but no more than batchSize objects’ data will be fetched from the persistent store at a time. The array returned from executing the request will be a proxy object that transparently faults batches on demand.

So if the managed object context is not attached to a persistent store, there is nothing to fetch against - so the behavior you are seeing is at least somewhat consistent with the documentation. fetchLimit may work in the scenario you are describing. I would still fire a radar on it at bugreporter.apple.com .